# Merged avhdx file and now VM fails to start since the avhdx file cannot be found

Tags: hyper-v

My HyperV VM fails to start since it cannot find its avhdx file; which should be merged AFAIK.
How do I get HyperV(?) to understand that the avhdx file has been merged?

I had a virtual machine Foss06 with 2 files. `Foss06.vhdx` and `Foss06_A1EBE5BC-A1E2-4169-B799-E3AAAA9B73D0.avhdx`
I merged the avhdx file through the HyperV GUI. [(instructions)](https://trevorsullivan.net/2016/07/24/merge-hyper-v-disks/)
Now I cannot start Foss06 any more but instead get a

> The application encountered an error while attempting to change the
> state of 'Foss06'.
>
> 'Foss06' failed to start.
>
> Synthetic SCSI Controller (Instance ID
> 815FD6A9-8FD9-4DEA-9D1C-22E4F58A2CC5): Failed to Power on with Error
> 'The system cannot find the file specified.'.
>
> Attachment 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard
> Disks\Foss06_04F4F225-DC4A-4A1B-AEEE-3897A293FE1B.avhdx' could not be
> found due to error: 'The system cannot find the file specified.'.
>
> [Expanded Information] 'Foss06' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID
> 4885E72F-2780-4114-AF12-1FAB26973AE8)
>
> 'Foss06' Synthetic SCSI Controller (Instance ID
> 815FD6A9-8FD9-4DEA-9D1C-22E4F58A2CC5): Failed to Power on with Error
> 'The system cannot find the file specified.' (0x80070002). (Virtual
> machine ID 4885E72F-2780-4114-AF12-1FAB26973AE8)
>
> 'Foss06': Attachment 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard
> Disks\Foss06_04F4F225-DC4A-4A1B-AEEE-3897A293FE1B.avhdx' could not be
> found due to error: 'The system cannot find the file specified.'
> (0x80070002). (Virtual machine ID
> 4885E72F-2780-4114-AF12-1FAB26973AE8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the HyperV GUI pointed to a avhdx file.
Connect...->...Hard drive->Browse...

I and pointed it at the vhdx file instead. (maybe I did an Inspect, can't remember)
It tried to create a checkpoint, failed, threw up a dialogue about naming, and failed; so I just pressed continue. Now my VM starts.

(Caveat: I wouldn't hack around like I did in a production environment, but as I am just [experimenting with development machines](https://www.selfelected.com/experimenting-with-setting-up-a-new-machine-every-third-month/) it felt safe enough.)